# React-native get phone call history ( Android / iOS )

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there any react-native api / open source project that allows you to retrieve call history ( incoming / missed / outgoing ) in android / iOS ? Google search for it wasn't very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out there isnt any. decided to write my own native module for it and use react native binding to read the json data from it

Comment: Edit your answer with code. so that any one can use that code.

Comment: @RaviKumar He shouldn't have to. Importing your own modules is pretty basic and getting call history isn't that hard in C or swift.

Comment: you can use npm package like react-native-call-log  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-log
 to get call history

Comment: @VinodRanga that is for android only